# Possible to change the distance of a diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I write this in Latex:

```
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=3.5em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
            {F   & \supset  &A     &      C  \\ 
             X   & \supset  &B     &         \\};
        \path[->]
                (m-1-1) edge node[left] {$ \pi $} (m-2-1)
                (m-1-3) edge node[auto] {$ f $} (m-1-4)
                (m-2-3) edge node[auto] {$ \sigma $} (m-1-3)
                        edge (m-1-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And my problem is, that the map `\pi: F \rightarrow X` and the two `\supset` are too wide regarding the commutative diagram on the right side (and vice versa). How can I change this, but in this way, that everything is one below the other. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please include the definition of `\IC`.

Comment: Preferably provide a complete example we can compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're after, but I'll note that you can specify the `column sep` for individual columns by adding e.g. `[1cm]` immediately after a `&` in the *first row*.

In the code below, I removed your original `column sep` setting, and added `[3.5em]` in the matrix.

(Note that `graphicx` loads `graphics`, so there's no need to load both. And `tikz` loads `pgf`, so the latter can be removed. And because `tikz` loads `graphicx`, you really just need `\usepackage{tikz}`. And `amsfonts` for  `\mathbb`

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[description/.style={fill=white,inner sep=2pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em,  text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
            {F   & \supset  &\pi^{-1}(U_{i})     &[3.5em]        U_{i} \times \mathbb{C}      \\ 
             X   & \supset  &   U_{i}            &                        \\};
        \path[->]
                (m-1-1) edge node[left] {$ \pi $} (m-2-1)
                (m-1-3) edge node[auto] {$ f_{i} $} (m-1-4)
                (m-2-3) edge node[auto] {$ \sigma $} (m-1-3)
                      edge (m-1-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]